# node REPL gaves me an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, read-eval-print-loop, manjaro

## Here is my code

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema } = mongoose;
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false); 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/moviesdb')
.then(()=> {
    console.log("Connection Open")
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log("error")
    console.log(err)
})

const movieSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    year: Number,
    score: Number,
    rating: String,
});

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema)
const amadeus = new Movie({title: 'Amadeus', year: 1986})
```

When I tried

```
node
```

and

```
.load index.js
```

I got infinite loop says

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
```

I followed instructions on Mongoose website but it gaves me that bug.
I'm using latest version of Manjaro Linux, and node version is up to date.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, edit your question to include error details needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75121070/438992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in node that has recently developed (at least all the complaints I've seen about it are from 2023), but it is present in both the LTS (v18) and the most current version (v19) of node. As a an alternative, using the bash shell (gitbash), or (I've heard) ubuntu, enter:

```
node -i -e "$(< index.js)"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75121070/438992