# Why does using the .load special command in NodeJS v18 result in an infinite loop of loading the first line of the specified file?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to load a 6 line js file into the Node REPL using the .load function:

```js
function reverse(string) { 
  return string.split("").reverse().join("");
}

function palindrome(string) {
  return string === reverse(string);
}
```

The result is an infinite loop printing the first line of the file (see image). I have to kill the terminal to make it stop loading this one line of code.  Is this a bug in Node, or am I missing something?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS and Node.js v18.13.0.

```
en@dangerous:~/Documents/tutorial/js_tutorial$ node
Welcome to Node.js v18.13.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> .load palindrome.js
```

[image: Terminal Window]

Comment: Same under OS X; 18.12.1/18.13.0 breakage. Didn't see anything obvious in the change log.

Answer (score 1):

I am also going through the Learn Enough to be Dangerous courses and I ran into exactly the same problem.

As far as I can tell it has something to do with the node version since I was also in Node v18.13.0. I also tried 19.6.1 but the same thing happened.

I decided to go backward and attempted to use 14.20.0 and low and behold I was able to run the palindrome.js file in a repl with node. I haven't tested versions in between 14.20.0 and 18.13.0, so im not sure which version this started happening with.

Update---
I did some trial and error and I found that the issue starts specifically with 18.13.0. 18.12.1 runs the palindrome.js file just fine.

For anyone curious this is what is in the palindrome.js file:

```js
// Reverses a string.
function reverse(string){
    return Array.from(string).reverse().join("");
}

// Defines a Phrase Object.
function Phrase(content){
    this.content = content;

    // Returns true for a palindrome, false otherwise.
    this.palindrome = function palindrome(){
        let processedContent = this.content.toLowerCase();
        return processedContent === reverse(processedContent);
    }

    // makes the phrase louder.
    this.louder = function(){
        return this.content.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that [started in v18.13](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/46742#issuecomment-1445923987) and was [discovered by someone using v19.6](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/46731). A fix has been made in this PR: [repl: fix .load infinite loop caused by shared use of lineEnding RegExp
#46742](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/46742). The PR [has been merged into the v19](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V19.md), but not yet into v18. [I commented there to make a request that the fix be backported into v18](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/46742#issuecomment-1474954598), since at the time of this writing, [v18 is in "Active LTS" status](https://nodejs.dev/en/about/releases/). That seems to have been done in [commit `09739a2`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/09739a20b109c1bed30a4e407852438fb61ae9d3). See [the 18.16 release proposal](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/47502).