# Is it possible to run a single one function in Visual Studio Code's terminal?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, console

I wrote a very simple multiply function:

```js
function multiply (x) {
    return x * 2;
}
```

If I link my js file with a html file and run the console in Dev Tools, I can just type in "multiply(2)" to get the answer "4" without any errors.

Is there any option, to run the function in Visual Studio Code's terminal? So I don't habe to link every single js file with a single, simple function with html file?

I'm using NodeJS. But when I type in "node nameofjsfile.js" to run the program, and then for example "multiply(2)", the program doesn't work and I get ObjectNowFound, CommandNotFoundException. If I write "node nameofjsfile.js multiply(2)", I get "Syntax error, Code: 800A03EA".

Comment: the browser is a JavaScript REPL, the terminal is NOT, maybe there is a NodeJS REPL you can use

Comment: why do you think `node nameofjsfile.js` would leave some stuff behind after executing the script. If you run a WordProcessor and exit the tool does it leave some stuff behind, if it does it has a memory leak and that needs to be fixed

Comment: @rioV8 I though memory leaks are only a problem while the program runs. Shouldn't any good OS clean up memory after a program exits?

Comment: @user if you allocate shared memory it will not be freed by the OS, The point I want to make is that the Terminal is not a REPL

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal shell is not a JavaScript REPL. You can run NodeJS in interactive mode to get a JavaScript REPL. If you want to load a file into a NodeJS REPL, use [the `.load` special command](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#commands-and-special-keys). Or you can turn your JavaScript file into a CommonJS module by [exporting your `multiply` function](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#exports-shortcut) and then `require()` your JS file into the NodeJS REPL.

<sup>Note: At the time of this writing, NodeJS v18 has a bug with the `.load` command. See [Why does using the .load special command in NodeJS v18 result in an infinite loop of loading the first line of the specified file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75121070/11107541)</sup>

As for why you got those specific error message with your failed attempts:

> I'm using NodeJS. But when I type in "node nameofjsfile.js" to run the program, and then for example "multiply(2)", the program doesn't work and I get ObjectNotFound, CommandNotFoundException.

This is because your ran NodeJS and told it to exit after running your script. It ran your script and then exited, returning control of the terminal input to the shell you're using.

> If I write "node nameofjsfile.js multiply(2)", I get "Syntax error, Code: 800A03EA".

This is not a valid way to invoke NodeJS to do what you want. And the error is probably happening with something related to how the shell you're using parses the command (perhaps something with the brackets).